# Comparing Drone CI/CD to GitHub Actions and GitLab CI/CD - Advantages and Real-World Scenarios

Tags: drone.io

I am currently evaluating different CI/CD tools for my project and trying to understand the unique advantages of each. I've come across Drone CI/CD, which is known for its lightweight design, easy setup, and extensibility through plugins.

I already know about the great features of GitHub Actions and GitLab CI/CD, but I'm curious to learn more about the specific advantages that Drone CI/CD offers over these popular alternatives.

While I have read that Drone CI/CD's lightweight nature makes it easy to set up and its plugin ecosystem provides extensibility, I would like to know more about real-world scenarios where it outperforms GitHub Actions and GitLab CI/CD.

For instance, in what situations is Drone CI/CD particularly well-suited? Are there any use cases where Drone CI/CD shines due to its simplicity and flexibility? Does it offer any unique benefits for microservices, containerized applications, or self-hosted environments?

I appreciate any insights and experiences from developers who have used Drone CI/CD, as well as comparisons to GitHub Actions and GitLab CI/CD in specific use cases. Thank you for your valuable input!

Not applicable. (N/A)